# Moving Windows 7 Internet History to new user profile

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, internet-explorer-9, user-profiles

I've had a Windows 7, IE9 user with a corrupt profile so I renamed his profile to `user.old` and recreated his profile as `user.domain`.

All of his files have been moved successfully except for his Internet History. I have copied across his Temporary Internet Files (pretty sure this was unnecessary but I was clutching at straws by the end) and copied across his History folder (from `c:\users\user.old\appdata\local\microsoft\Windows\history` to `c:\users\user.domain\appdata\local\microsoft\Windows\history`).

I copied the folder across as Local Admin, in Safe Mode.

Initially I renamed the History folder that Windows had just created to `history.temp` and pasted in the old history folder from the old profile (just called `History`). On reboot nothing had changed.

I have since tried deleting the "new" history folder completely and dropping the old one in its place. All this did was delete the very newest history but still didn't add the older items.

Is there something I'm missing? Is there some hidden link, metadata or registry key that needs changing too?

Comment: I have just tried the "Easy Transfer" wizard, but it crashed as soon as I tried to select the History folder in the customise settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Easy Transfer Wizard fixed this in the end. Despite crashing the first time it ran fine after a restart. Although the dates are lost, all the websites are there.